# Проблема с PySide2 "NameError: name 'QtWidgets' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, импорт

проблема у меня такая : Недавно перешёл с PySide на PySide2, и к моему удивлению множество команд в PySide2 отличаются от тех которые используются в PySide но не отличается импортированная строка `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)`, с которой у меня и выходить следующая ошибка

```
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
NameError: name 'QtWidgets' is not defined
```

Помогите, с чем связана эта ошибка?

Мой Python 3.7.0

Все установленные модули -

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
geojson==2.5.0
idna==2.10
pyowm==3.1.1
PyQt5==5.15.1
PyQt5-sip==12.8.1
PySide2==5.15.1
PySocks==1.7.1
QtPy==1.9.0
requests==2.24.0
shiboken2==5.15.1
urllib3==1.25.10
```

Спасибо вам!

Comment: покажите ваши импорты. У вас есть импорт `from PySide2 import QtWidgets` ?

Comment: S. Nick Извините за долгое ожидание, у меня были проблемы с сетью. Вот все мои импорты: `import sys`

Comment: Добавьте импорты `from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui`